# ~ not working from read command

Tags: bash, cd, tilde-expansion

I have a script where I am trying to have a user enter the PATH to a command. And most of the time, this command is going to live in the user directory, so more often than not, the PATH will be entered using the ~ sign.

The code looks essentially like this (for simplicity of debugging):

```
echo -n "Enter PATH to start-site command and press [ENTER]: "
read startSite

cd $startSite
./start-site.sh $repositoryName $DIR/..
```

but I just get an error saying ~/my/path isn't a file or directory. If I copy and paste the command from the error into the terminal, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: `eval cd $startSite`

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Kenyon, be extremely careful with `eval` -- suppose the user enters `$(rm -f /my/valuable/directory/)`: once you eval that, your valuable files are deleted. Might be better to do: `read startSite; startSite=$(sed "s,^~,$HOME," <<<"$startSite"); cd "$startSite"`

Comment: I'm not really worried about it. It's just a utility command for like 3 people in the office. I don't think any of them are going to try rm -rf ='ing there computer from a tool designed to create a new site boilerplate haha xD

Comment: Unquoted `startSite` will only work if the directory name doesn't contain any spaces or glob characters, though.